# Como imprimir no Android através de uma impressora bluetooth?

Tags: android, bluetooth, impressora

Estive a pesquisar e não encontrei nada sobre imprimir no Android através de uma impressora por bluetooth. É possível fazer isso? Existe alguma biblioteca ou SDK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, é possível! Trabalho numa empresa que tem produtos para dispositivos móveis e em um deles a gente utiliza impressão bluetooth, em uma pequena impressora adquirida do exterior. A impressora veio com o SDK necessário para utilizá-la, bem como exemplo de aplicação em Android.

Comment: O SDK é software livre?

Comment: Talvez eu não tenha utilizado o termo correto, o SDK funciona mais como um Driver, específico para aquele dispositivo. Ele vem junto com o produto e o produto é pago.

Comment: É bom saber que funciona pelo menos, mas precisava de qualquer coisa que funcionasse para a maioria das impressoras. Claro que depois teria de se implementar de forma a que deixasse incluir vários drivers.

Comment: Eu não sei se existe uma forma que funcione dessa maneira, mas se existir, realmente seria bacana.